# EXCEL QUE SE DESCARGA DESDE EL NAVEGADOR CON FORMATO FALLIDO

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

estoy usando PhpSpreadSheet para descargar excel con php, pero al descargar el archivo me sale con un formato de texto corrupto, si no uso las cabeceras no tengo el mismo problema, solo lo uso cuando coloco los siguientes head:

`````
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. urlencode($file_name).'"'); ```
Es el codigo que uso para crear las celdas en excel.
```     $file = new Spreadsheet(0,'RESUMEN');
    `$active_sheet = $file->getActiveSheet();`
    `$active_sheet->setCellValue('A1','ID');`
    `$active_sheet->setCellValue('B1','NOMBRE');`
    `$active_sheet->setCellValue('C1','APELLIDO');````
`````

```
    $sqlquery = $conn->prepare('SPU_RESUMEN_COTIZACION ?,?,?,?,?');
    $sqlquery->execute([$fechaI, $fechaF, $estado, $cliente, $asesor]);

    while($fila = $sqlquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $active_sheet->setCellValue('A'.$count, $fila['ID']);
        $active_sheet->setCellValue('B'.$count, $fila['NOMBRE']);
        $active_sheet->setCellValue('C'.$count, $fila['APELLIDO']);
$count = $count + 1;
```

Adjunto foto de como se ve el excel cuando lo descargo.[image: Formato del excel cuando añado las cabeceras]

Tengo la duda si hay otra manera de descargar desde el navegador sin usar las cabeceras o si a alguien le ha pasado este problema, agradezco su apoyo.

Comment: ¿Por qué si es un Excel pones un `Content-Type: text/html;` ¿?

Comment: Se me paso, lo tengo comentado en mi código, y aun así tengo el problema. header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); esta línea es la que uso arriba.

Comment: En la pregunta debes poner todo el código que estás manejando para obtener el Excel, así como cualquier error que veas en pantalla. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: No tengo error alguno la verdad, cuando no uso las cabeceras, no tengo ese error, me sale el excel limpio, el problema es que sin esos header no puedo descargarlo a mi navegador y se descarga a la carpeta en donde tengo mi proyecto.

Comment: Se supone que el Excel se construye de algún modo o es tomado de alguna parte... todo eso falta en tu código. ¿Cómo obtienes el Excel? ¿Revisaste el log de errores?

Comment: Si claro, no tengo error alguno en el  log, el excel lo obtengo usando la libreria PhpSpreadSheet usando setCellValue('Letra , Numero Fila', 'Nombre').

Comment: Yo sigo viendo en tu código este header: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` no un header propio para un archivo Excel. Tienes que poner en la pregunta el código como lo tienes. ¿Tienes el código tal cual aparece en la pregunta? Si es así, tienes un `Content-Type` erróneo que corromperá el Excel.

Comment: Ya esta tal cual, aún así me sigue saliendo ese error.

Comment: No veo el código con el que das salida el Excel.

Comment: Amigo tienes alguna linea similar a esta $writer = new Xlsx($Spreadsheet);  ??

Comment: los 2 primeros caracteres `PK` apuntan a un posible [archivo comprimido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Local_file_header) abrilo con un manejador de archives a ver si contiene la estructura válida de [OOXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) y si la versión de excel lo soporta.

Answer (score 0):

**Bueno asegurate de usar el 'SpreadSheet' y el 'Writer Xlsx' se ve algo así:**

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```

Despues iniciar tu hoja de calculo; en tu caso lo tienes como `$file = New SpreadSheet();`

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

//En esta parte van las columnas y el proceso en si
```

**Posicionar la hoja activa ya sea por índice o nombre**

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
//Si tienes varias hojas puedes seleccionarlas por indice
//$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

**Ahora sigue la exportación o salida del documento, en mi caso yo lo tengo al final de mi documento, hasta el final;**

```
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet); // Escribir un archivo .xlsx aquí iria su $file
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. urlencode($fileName).'"'); //$fileName el nombre del archivo en si
$writer->save('php://output'); //Exportarlo fuera
```

Puedes checar algunos ejemplos en la misma documentación

De igual forma te dejo el que utilicé de manera más personalizada, solo se agregan algunas propiedades más al documento, pero lo importante para exportar es el `$writer->save('php://output');`

Custom export:

```
//Save report
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fileName.'-reporte-excel.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Expires: Fri, 11 Nov 2011 11:11:11 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Fuentes:
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worksheets/
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/